# Notification at change of status

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I am newbie in programming, so I'm asking to be, let's say, more patient. Thanks.

Now what I want to ask.
So I have a discord bot that check minecraft server status. By checking server status it set for himself Playing status like "Playing x/y players" or "Server unavailable". I want to make notifications when it will send message if status "Server unavailable" changes to "Playing", so users of my discord server get notified when server up. More better will be if notifications will be sent only if server was unavailable for more than X minutes.

One more thing. I do Not ask for sample code, but for directions for what I'm should Google, so I can write code by myself.

Thanks for any help!

Oh btw, bot is written on Node.js.

Comment: I don't know about a notification, but you could send Direct Messages to all users in a server, or mention @everyone in a TextChannel when the server is available after it is down

Comment: well yeah, i meant by default to sent in server @everyone message, but i dont know how to make it